# proc template to fix attribute class header in proc report sas

Tags: templates, sas, report, proc

i am trying to put in proc template the style of proc report

```
PROC TEMPLATE;
   DEFINE STYLE Styles.mine;
      PARENT=styles.htmlblue;
      CLASS systitleandfootercontainer / htmlstyle="border:none";
         CLASS header /
               color=white
               backgroundcolor=blue;
   END;
RUN;

ods html file=outbox rs=none style=styles.mine;

proc report data=WORK.1 nowd style=styles.mine;
... report code;

proc report data=WORK.2 nowd style=styles.mine;
```

it's not changing the attribute of header, and i don't find any documentation that can explain me what am i doing wrong